Requesting Sepolia Test ETH for Development
I am currently working on a smart contract project and need some Sepolia test ETH to deploy and test my contracts. Unfortunately, I have been unable to obtain test ETH from the available faucets due to various restrictions.
Could anyone kindly send a small amount of Sepolia test ETH to my address below? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Wallet Address: 0x429228770c8cEb3D5609eA6ECe33363438090F63
Thank you in advance for your help!

I sent you 0.25 Sepolia ETH.
You can obtain free Sepolia ETH at https://faucets.chain.link/.
